# How can I create a networkx graph from a DataFrame where edges are based on Boolean slicing on another column in the DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, networkx

Say I have a DataFrame:

```
    Col1    Col2
0   Bob     6
1   Bob     5
2   Bob     17
3   Joe     54
4   Frank   12
5   Joe     9
6   Frank   707
7   Frank   24
8   Frank   76
```

I want to create a Networkx graph such that the nodes are based off of Col2 and the edges are based off of Col1. In other words, if this DataFrame were converted to source and target lists, they'd be:

```
source = [5, 5, 6, 9, 12, 12, 12, 707, 707, 24]
target = [6, 17, 17, 54, 707, 24, 76, 24, 76, 76]
```

All of the `'Bob'` items are grouped together, so there're edges between 5, 6, and 17, etc.

Is there a way to do this? I'm wracking my brain and not coming up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `groupby` with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx

edges = (df
 .groupby('Col1')['Col2']
 .agg(lambda x: list(combinations(x, r=2)))
 .explode()
)

G = nx.from_edgelist(edges)

G.edges()
```

Output:

```
EdgeView([(6, 5), (6, 17), (5, 17), (12, 707), (12, 24), (12, 76), (707, 24), (707, 76), (24, 76), (54, 9)])
```

Comment: I got a "TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()" error.

Comment: @JohnDoe this error doesn't make sense. What is the full error traceback? Also please provide the DataFrame constructor of your input for reproducibility.

Comment: It ended up being moot: my data has 5300 nodes in 1300 distinct groups and over 880,000 edges. Turns out that the network analysis packages have the edges "on" all the time, which is unnecessary for my purposes and DRASTICALLY slows down the performance of the graph, so I'm having to resort to using bokeh's CustomJS callback features, which is a bummer because I'm passable with Python but I know Jack-diddly JavaScript.